# Can't use public IP when ssh into local workstation

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am trying to ssh into my workstation. I have started the ssh server and forwarded port 22 to the private IP of that specific machine. I am currently able to ssh to that workstation server **remotely**. The issue right now is when I try to ssh into that machine when I am on the same network. Using

```
ssh -vvvv username@mydns.org
```

I get:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ddong/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ddong/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "mydns.duckdns.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mydns.duckdns.org [192.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ddong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

And it simply hangs there. No error message. (Maybe a connection timeout if I let it run longer.)

This is only a problem when ssh-ing from this local network from my laptop. From my laptop, I tried to first ssh into a remote machine elsewhere, and ssh to this workstation and it works. Another thing that works is connecting to a VPN prior to ssh-ing. Finally, another thing that works is ssh-ing using the private IP instead of the public one.

Ideally, I could always use the public one, since I could use that DNS independently of where I am.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: I think changing the port listening for SSH would fix the problem and be much more secure at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! To clarify, are you having issues when trying to connect using your public IP address when on the same local network as the server?

Comment: Trying to change the listening port for SSH. Having some hiccups and can't connect to it from anywhere when I do. Edited the sshd_config, restarted the sshd service and checked that it was running on that new port, added it to the list through firewall-config, and changed the port forwarding. Unfortunately now I can't connect to it at all.

@HazardousGlitch, yes I am trying to connect to it using my public IP address when on the same local network, which doesn't work. Using the private IP does.

Comment: "using my public IP address when on the same local network" - It's not suppose to.  Why are you against using the private ip address, when you are dealing, with a intranet client?

Comment: @Ramhound I was just going to set a single alias to ssh into that specific machine. It's not a "true issue" since I can always either use the public or private IP depending on my current location. However, it would be nice to have a single way to connect to that machine. For example, I might be running a VPN on my laptop, and all of a sudden, I need to use the public address.